# The best way to apply the same trigger on multiple databases in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

What is the best way to apply one trigger over multiple databases suppose there are available 10 and 20 databases.

Comment: What would be wrong with just using the same logic in more than one trigger?  Or, are you asking about what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: actually i'm asking possible way and best of them.

Comment: i want at least best way

Comment: You never tagged with your database, so I will offer this just as a suggestion.  You will need to define triggers on all tables AFAIK, but there may be some ways to reuse code.  For example, you could have each trigger call a common stored procedure.

Comment: I'm not asking  "same logic in more than one trigger" I'm asking "Same trigger on multiple databases"

Comment: You write an  SQL script and run it against which ever cli tool your db uses?

Comment: A trigger in SQL Server is always bound to a single table but i want apply different databases with different table using one trigger.

Comment: "A trigger in SQL Server is always bound to a single table", exactly.  So "different databases with different table using one trigger" is impossible.

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` as the answer posted clearly is for that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer actually it is possible

just define 'on all server' within trigger
example

```
create trigger Trigger_Name
on all server
for logon
as
  begin
.....
end
```